# Angular 2 async pipe does not refresh

Tags: angular, rxjs

I am trying to get information from an API and put the data in a HTML Table.

When I load the component, sometimes the table is loading properly and sometimes it stays blank. By checking in the network tab in the debugger, the API responds properly on every request. Also, I don't get any errors in the console.

Here is my service :

```
import 'rxjs/Rx';
import {Injectable} from 'angular2/core';
import {Http, Response} from 'angular2/http';

import { Fishtank } from './fishtank';

@Injectable()
export class FishtanksService {
    constructor(private _http: Http) {
    }

    getFishtanks() {
        var response = this._http.get("http://localhost:10239/api/fishtank");
        return response.map((response: Response) => <Fishtank[]>response.json().fishtanks);
    }
}
```

Here is the component that is using this service :

```
import {Component, OnInit} from 'angular2/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Rx';

import {Fishtank} from './fishtank';
import {FishtanksService} from './fishtanks.service';

@Component({
    selector: 'fishtanks',
    templateUrl: `<div>
                    <table class="table table-striped table-condensed">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>id </th>
                                <th> batchNumber </th>
                                <th> userGroup </th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody >
                            <tr *ngFor="#fishtank of fishtanks | async">
                                <td>{{fishtank.id }}</td>
                                <td> {{fishtank.batchNumber }}</td>
                                <td> {{fishtank.userGroup }}</td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                     </table>
                </div>
                <button (click)="click()">Click me</button>`
})

export class FishtanksComponent implements OnInit {
    constructor(private _fishtanksService: FishtanksService) {
    }

    public fishtanks: Observable<Fishtank[]>;

    public getFishtanks() {
        this.fishtanks = this._fishtanksService.getFishtanks();
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.getFishtanks()
    }
    public click() {
    }
}
```

However, as you can see above, I tried to add a simple button to the template with a (click) event that does nothing. When I click this button, the table is refreshed and shows the data properly.

I don't know if this issue is linked to angular2 or rxjs.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Somehow Angular doesn't get notified about some event to do it's change detection. Do you use `Http` as shown in your question or do you actually use some other library to fetch the data from thw server?

Comment: Instead of using the `| async` pipe you could try `this._fishtanksService.getFishtanks().subscribe(value => this.fishtanks = value);`

Comment: I use Http as shown, i'll try with subscribe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed the problem by rearranging the reference in index.html.

Here is the order that made it not work :

```
<script src="libs/angular2-polyfills.js"></script>
<script src="libs/es6-shim.min.js"></script>
<script src="libs/system-polyfills.js"></script>
<script src="libs/shims_for_IE.js"></script>
<script src="libs/system.js"></script>
<script src="libs/rx.js"></script>
<script src="libs/angular2.dev.js"></script>
<script src="libs/router.dev.js"></script>
<script src="libs/http.dev.js"></script>
```

Here is the order that fixed it :

```
<script src="libs/es6-shim.min.js"></script>
<script src="libs/system-polyfills.js"></script>
<script src="libs/shims_for_ie.js"></script>
<script src="libs/angular2-polyfills.js"></script>
<script src="libs/system.js"></script>
<script src="libs/rx.js"></script>
<script src="libs/angular2.dev.js"></script>
<script src="libs/router.dev.js"></script>
<script src="libs/http.dev.js"></script>
```